# Array passed by reference is not updated in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to pass an array to a C++ class, in order the make the changes to the array objects visible outside the class. But it is not working. The changes to the `Motor` objects are lost after every call.

It's an Arduino project using the [ESPAsyncWebServer](https://github.com/me-no-dev/ESPAsyncWebServer). Not sure whether this matters.

See [the project on github](https://github.com/pluess/workbench-lift/tree/460a0ce51d714dbc493501137636634666d09e60) for full source code.

In the `setup()` method I'm defining the array and pass it into the the web-server:

```
void setup()
{
    std::array<Motor, NOF_MOTORS> motorArray = {
        Motor(1, 0, 1, DEFAULT_PWM),
        Motor(2, 2, 3, DEFAULT_PWM)};

    server.addHandler(new RequestHander(motorArray));
}
```

The `RequestHandler` constructor is taking the array by reference:

```
class RequestHander : public AsyncWebHandler
{
    public:
        RequestHander(std::array<Motor, NOF_MOTORS> &motorArray) : motorArray_(motorArray) {}
    private:
        std::array<Motor, NOF_MOTORS> motorArray_;
}
```

Any ideas why the Motor objects are not changed? To me it feels as if they were some how passed by value.

Comment: The `motorArray_` member is not a reference.

Comment: C++ is not Java.  C++ is value-based, not reference-based.  When you did this: `motorArray_(motorArray)` a *copy* of the entire `std::array` is created and set to `motorArray_`, and not a reference to the passed-in `array`.

Comment: Fully agree. That's what I see happening. Any hints how to avoid the copy?

Comment: You can't avoid it since `motorArray` is a locally scoped variable.

Comment: So what would be suitable software design in C++ to update shared data in a webrequest?

Comment: Was your goal to actually make `motorArray` and `motorArray_` refer to the same object?  If so, then that's what `std::shared_ptr` is designed for.  You could also make `motorArray_` a reference member variable, but that comes at a cost (for example, the class is not easily copyable and assignable, due to having members that are reference variables).

Comment: *To me it feels as if they were some how passed by value.* -- No, the value was passed by reference.  The issue is the second-part of the equation, and that is `motorArray_(motorArray)`, and that makes a copy.

Comment: While there is enough code to see what is likely the problem, your code should be complete enough so that someone can copy-compile-run it to see a symptom of the problem. This should be simple for you to add, as you would just need to make a change to an array object, then send output to `std::cout` to demonstrate that the intended change is not visible where you want it to be. *My main concern with the current code is that the `motorArray` in `setup()` goes out of scope when the function ends, making it hard to see how you hope to change it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are passing the `std::array` *by reference* into the `RequestHander()` constructor, but you are then making a *copy* of the array (and thus a *copy* of the `Motor` objects) when initializing the `motorArray_` member, which is not a reference.  So, any subsequent changes you make to the `motorArray_` elements are not reflected back to the original array.

You *could* change the `motorArray_` member into a reference, eg:

```
std::array<Motor, NOF_MOTORS>& motorArray_;
```

But this would be very dangerous in the code you have shown, because the original `std::array` is a local variable of `setup()` and will go out of scope when `setup()` exits, leaving `motorArray_` *dangling*.

So, you have some options:

- change `RequestHander` to take ownership of the original `std::array` before it goes out of scope:

  ```
  #include <array>
  #include <memory>

  void setup()
  {
      auto motorArray = std::make_unique<std::array<Motor, NOF_MOTORS>>();
      (*motorArray)[0] = Motor(1, 0, 1, DEFAULT_PWM);
      (*motorArray)[1] = Motor(2, 2, 3, DEFAULT_PWM);

      server.addHandler(new RequestHander(std::move(motorArray)));
  }
  ```

  ```
  #include <array>
  #include <memory>

  class RequestHander : public AsyncWebHandler
      {
      public:
          RequestHander(std::unique_ptr<std::array<Motor, NOF_MOTORS>> motorArray) : motorArray_(std::move(motorArray)) {}
      private:
          std::unique_ptr<std::array<Motor, NOF_MOTORS>> motorArray_;
  };
  ```

  Alternatively, if you don't strictly need the `std::array`:

  ```
  #include <memory>

  void setup()
  {
      auto motorArray = std::make_unique<Motor[]>(NOF_MOTORS);
      motorArray[0] = Motor(1, 0, 1, DEFAULT_PWM);
      motorArray[1] = Motor(2, 2, 3, DEFAULT_PWM);

      server.addHandler(new RequestHander(std::move(motorArray)));
  }
  ```

  ```
  #include <memory>

  class RequestHander : public AsyncWebHandler
  {
      public:
          RequestHander(std::unique_ptr<Motor[]> motorArray) : motorArray_(std::move(motorArray)) {}
      private:
          std::unique_ptr<Motor[]> motorArray_;
  };
  ```
- change the `std::array` itself to hold pointers to `Motor` objects, but pass around the array itself by reference and move the pointers as needed:

  ```
  #include <array>
  #include <memory>

  void setup()
  {
      std::array<std::unique_ptr<Motor>, NOF_MOTORS> motorArray = {
          std::make_unique<Motor>(1, 0, 1, DEFAULT_PWM),
          std::make_unique<Motor>(2, 2, 3, DEFAULT_PWM)
      };

      server.addHandler(new RequestHander(std::move(motorArray)));
  }
  ```

  ```
  #include <array>
  #include <memory>
  #include <algorithm>

  class RequestHander : public AsyncWebHandler
  {
      public:
          RequestHander(std::array<std::unique_ptr<Motor>, NOF_MOTORS> &&motorArray) {
              std::move(motorArray.begin(), motorArray.end(), motorArray_.begin());
          }
      private:
          std::array<std::unique_ptr<Motor>, NOF_MOTORS> motorArray_;
  };
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time! Unfortunately I had to learn that Arduino is still at C++ 11. `std::make_unique` is not available. So what I did is make motorArray global and changed the `motorArray_` member into a reference as you sugested. It's working now after all.

Comment: @BetaRide `std::unique_ptr` is in C++11, and `std::make_unique()` is easy to code manually. Or you can use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared()` in C++11